# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c++, string

```
if (nrg < "10")
{
     client.ShopUse();
}
```

I'm really confused about the lesser than operator in c++.
Why doesn't this work on strings?

Comment: What type does `nrg` have?

Comment: @Evg I thought that it didn't have it, due to the existence of this question.. I was wrong :(

Comment: Convert the strings into numbers and then compare them. You can't compare strings. Well you can e.g. using strcmp in C, but it wont give you the results you expect.

Comment: @Owl "_You can't compare strings._" Sure you can, as I've been proven wrong already: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp .

Comment: Yes, as I say, it wont give you the results you expect.

Comment: @Owl "_it wont give you the results you expect_" 1) That depends on what one expects. 2) Still, one can compare strings, contrary to what you said. Even without the need to use `strcmp`, as you suggested.

Comment: You know what I said, stop being a try hard. What he expects is clearly a numeric comparison. Read the question. And YES I KNOW. But it wont give the results that he expects. Again. Read things before jumping on board and attacking someone.

Comment: any discord to help me fix this?

Comment: Rafly, I suspect the stoi answer is the one you should use

Comment: @Owl "_Read things before jumping on board and attacking someone._" Disagreeing with someone is not attacking someone. I read what you said. You said "_You can't compare strings._" That's clearly wrong (as I showed you). "can't compare strings." is different in meaning, from "wont give you the results you expect." Did you read what I've been telling you?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidzius you are being pedantically literal and argumentative. What i said was "You can't compare strings. Well you can e.g. using strcmp in C, but it wont give you the results you expect." It's not my fault you can't connect sentences together and want to score points being sanctimonious in a comment section.

Answer (score 2):

The less-than operator on strings does a lexicographical comparison on the strings. This compares strings in the same way that they would be listed in dictionary order, generalized to work for strings with non-letter characters.

For example:

```cpp
"a" < "b"
"a" < "ab"
"A" < "a"             (Since A has ASCII value 65; a has a higher ASCII value)
"cat" < "caterpillar"
```

For more information, look at the [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) algorithm, which the less-than operator usually invokes.

Comment: Nice answer. Note: if you want to convey the idea that a boolean expression is either `true` or `false` in your anwer, you can express it explicitly wit a `static_assert`, e.g., `static_assert("a" < "b");`.

Comment: Be very careful here. `"a" < "b"` compares the **addresses** of the string literals `"a"` and  `"b"`. It doesn't tell you anything meaningful. For purposes of this answer, those comparisons need explicit casts to `std::string`: `std::string("a") < std::string("b")`. And even then, the C++ standard does not require that `'a' < 'b'`; I don't know of a character encoding for which that isn't true, but `'A' < 'a'` is true when the compiler uses ASCII, but false when it uses EBCDIC.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using stoi to convert the string to an int

```
if (stoi(nrg) < stoi("10"))
                {
                    client.ShopUse();
                }
```

Comment: If I ever read `stoi("10")` in a source file, I'd spend a few useless minutes to wonder why the author didn't wrote `10` instead and check what `stoi` is (is it _really_ `std::stoi`?). In the context of a peer review, this is a rejection reason.

Answer (score 0):

If the questions is whether the value is between "0" and "9" (so no negative values) another way to check this would be

```cpp
if (nrg.size() == 1 && nrg[0] >= '0' && nrg[0] <= '9') {
  client.ShopUse();
}
```